# send_keys method not suggested in pycharm/python

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, sendkeys

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Yfw.png)

.send_keys() or .click() methods are not auto suggesting. If I write the method then the code works, but if I look for auto complete then it's not showing. Can someone please help me here? driver.find_element_by_name("name"). --> after the dot, it should auto suggest. Please see the screen shot.   Using Pycharm IDE

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\\Selenium Drivers\Chrome\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
driver.find_element_by_name("name").
```

Comment: Try waiting for some time: it shows for me immediately after I type `from selenium import webdriver`... If it doesn't show up, try changing the third line to `driver:webdriver.Chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\Selenium Drivers\Chrome\chromedriver.exe') ` so PyCharm thinks it has to search and index suggestions since we have explicitly declared that driver is of the data type `webdriver.Chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your PyCharm has not yet indexed the entire project. This could be cause by several things.

1. You have an incorrect interpreter configuration
2. Your python interpreter has no selenium installed
3. Your IDE just needs some time to index through a large project.

I believe that you should look in your interpreter configuration and check if selenium is installed.

**It could be done by pressing File->Settings->Python Interpreter**
[image: Python interpreter settings]

Here you can see all of your installed packages and your current project interpreter. If Selenium is not listed there you should install it by pressing **+** button

Comment: Thank you for answer.Yes i have selenium installed

Comment: You might want to check the configuration of your interpreter, this could also be the case